# Some styles from styled-components not applying when view with mobile device

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I ran into a problem which some styles on my website don't seem working when viewing on a mobile device. Where is my website: https://www.chingpingyang.club/

When I open it with my phone the submit button for the price filter and the price for books are having different styles from when I open the site with my laptop. And seems not only these two are not the same...

Here is the code for the submit button.

```
input {
        all: unset;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        width: 50px;
        height: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        color: ${props => props.theme.primWhite};
        background-color: ${props => props.theme.interactive};
        transition: 0.2s;
        &:hover {
            background-color: ${props => props.theme.interactiveDark};
        }
    }
```

Thank you all so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. It's caused by the "all: unset" I applied to the button. So just simply remove it and use other ways to remove the default button style.

Answer (score 0):

The issue does look to be button, but everything else. The button didn't change for me at all. Try this css below.

```css
@media (max-width: 800px){
    .sc-fzoyTs.jZUSDr {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .sc-fzoNJl.fvpgSY {
      width: calc(100% - 40px);
      border: 1px solid #efefef;
      padding: 1rem;
      margin: 0 auto 3rem;
    }
    .sc-fzoLsD.fYZyZu,
    .sc-fzqBZW.chhgrb {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .gpozzs {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .gpozzs label {
      width: auto;
      margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Bjorn.Thank you for answering my question. I have actually found out the problem. It's about the "all: unset" I applied to those buttons. It seems to clear out all inherit style for the button. So I just removed it and use other ways to clear out the default style. And it works. :)